How to install NodeJS 22 on AWS Lightsail
I have a NodeJS application, which I set up on Lightsail with Bitnami, and I want to upgrade to NodeJS 22, the current version with long-term support until 20227. AWS Lightsail only shows Bitnami 18, which has NodeJS 18, and not the more recent versions:

Why doesn't Bitnami package NodeJS versions after 18? To install NodeJS 22, is the only solution to do it from scratch with an OS and installing NodeJS and remaining programs by hand?
